# pipe ping output Line "Request timeout" into file

Tags: redirect, grep, timeout, output, ping

I need to capture only the "Request timeout" output line of ping into a file.

What does not work is:

```
ping server | grep Request > file.txt
ping server > file.txt 2>&1 | grep Request
```

Anyone any suggestions?

Host is OS X 10.9.x

Thanks in advance

L

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to modify buffering operation. Try following if "Request timeout" is stdout;
`ping server | stdbuf -o0 grep Request > file.txt`

otherwise if "Request timeout" is stderr
`ping server | stdbuf -e0 grep Request > file.txt`